# Java SQL Database Framework

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm looking for some java library/framework.

My usecase: I need to create and alter SQL Tables at runtime. I do not want to write all SQL queries by myself.

I'm looking for some kind of controller where I can just call something like:

```
controller.createTable("table1");
```

Later maybe something like

```
table.addColumn(...)
```

I hoped hibernate supports some kind of "dynamic entity management" but the 
solution with Dynamic Model
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-dynamicmodels.html
does not work as I want it to work :)

The regular user can create object (tables) at runtime. I do not want to apply any logic to this entities. only display the fields/columns.

So there is no "business logic".

Does anyone know some library, or does anyone know how to achieve this with hibernate?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Create A Method Or function .
Other Wise You can Create A class And that Have A One Method That have A singlr parameter Accept And This parameter is Table Name So Youe can delete your table By Controller Other Wise You May be A choose A Series That have I Developed But Not Intially Introduce Open Source So you can Contact Me And I Give A Suggestion.....

Comment: Hey, yeah I know i can create a method or function to wrap up table creation. But like I wrote, i do not want to :)

Creating table is not the part that's hard. I do not want to take care about the altering of tables and creating columns.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure weather altering data schemas within runtime is the right approach. Maybe it would be worth it to have more insights into your use case? What might be sufficient would be splitting the flexible data structure part (the one you would like to alter the data schema for) from the fixed part (e.g. searchable parts, things you would not alter like id columns) and use embedded JSON for your flexible stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Changing schema on runtime is not possible. I had experience with the same situation and what we have done to achieve that is we used CouchDB (no SQL) to achieve our goal. In which we created, updated, delete schema on user request. Go for NoSql approach as it does not require any schema.

Hope this helps you.